# How do I block access to Domain Name in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

If my site is domain.com & IP 1.1.1.1
Someone set the DNS Records of badsite.com to 1.1.1.1

How do I block the domain "badsite.com" from my website?

Apache & PHP

Comment: Unless apache is configured to handle domain requests for that badsite.com then they won't see your website. They'll get an error message from your server. Are you asking what if they simply redirect their website to yours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be able to block a referrer (using Apache) in your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} badsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Further reference: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-referrer/

Comment: Thank you. All files added to the page (e.g. css, js) are blocked, but the actual page is allowed. How can I block the actual page?

Comment: Your virtual host configuration should have the `ServerName` set. If it doesn't match the server name or server alias, it shouldn't even load. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html